# Do let bindings need an assignment operator for disambiguation?

Tags: syntax, parsing

Let's say I want to allow (conservative) let bindings, with optional type ascription. Most imperative languages would put a `=` or `:=` after the identifier, but wouldn't omitting the assignment operator work? Like this:

```
let <ident>[:<type>] <expr>;
```

Tuple assignments or record destructuring are also delimited

```
let { a, b, c } some_values();
```

**My question:** Is there any way that omitting the assignment operator as shown causes the let binding to be ambiguous?

I'm aware that languages like OCaml have a more powerful let binding syntax (like `let func arg1 arg2 = ...`), so I'm mostly talking about simpler implementations like Swift, Rust or Typescript.

Comment: The answer could be yes or no, depending on the syntax your language uses. Without a detailed specification of that syntax, we can't really answer. And if you did provide a detailed specification, this wouldn't be a very good question, as it wouldn't really be useful to anyone except you.

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to consider the interaction of possible keyword prefix operators for both types and expressions. For example:

```
let x: a b c
```

If you have a prefix `a` type operator (like `readonly` in TS), then the value is `c`. If you don't, but have a `b` prefix value operator (like `void` in JS), then the value is `b c`. If you have both then there's a potential ambiguity.

Obviously this would also apply to postfix keyword operators but I'm not aware of any of those offhand.

Comment: F# has postfix type operators, e.g. `int list`. I think they're common in ML-family languages.